# Is there any way to retrieve data from database on same page

Tags: php, sql

I have a page which pick data from SQL database and show in table (some columns of table are hidden). When I click on any row of table a modal launch.

I want to show detail of clicked row in modal which launch on same page without page refreshing.

Any help regarding this scenario?

Comment: What you've tried to so for  ?, show us

Comment: I have no idea of ajax so I want to do it without ajax.

Comment: Why are my question is downvoting ? any reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do in steps

- Each edit or view button should contain ID of the record
- On Click, get Record ID via JQuery
- Send AJAX or JQuery Request to fetch record based on record ID
- Publish that data in the modal
- On closing model, make all info clear

Answer Updated (JQuery exmaple)

```
var id = $(this).attr('id');
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'filename.php',
    data: "id="+ id,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
    //get response and populate data in model
}
```

Comment: According to your answer Ajax is necessary for this. So first I learn Ajax and then try.

Comment: Yup you can do using Ajax or JQuery. I just updated answer with jquery code.

Comment: Happy to know that you are from Pakistan.

Comment: @faisal97 thanks, you may email me if not working at ping@naveedramzan.com

Comment: I tried that method which is working perfectly. I want to know that how can i send more then 1 variable in Ajax?

Comment: @faisal97 do you want to send more than 1 variable for one record or you want to send multiple IDs to be opened ?